# Does the caches api work in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Does the caches API work in chrome extensions?

I have been looking for hours online and can't find an answer. I do not want to use the chrome.storage.local API since my extension should work hosted and as an extension. It should also run on all browsers and I don't want to have to create new API calls for these actions.

I have calls like the one below. They should store image URLs.It works fine when I run it through the browser via local host or otherwise but in the chrome extension it does nothing.

```
  const cache = await caches.open('unsplash-images');
  await cache.add(background.cachedImage.url);
```

I also add an array of uploaded files to the cache and access it later. But when doing this I the error shown below.

```
    if (addedFiles) {
        const cache = await caches.open("upload-images");

        const addedImages = Array.from(addedFiles);
        const existingImages = new Set(background.images);

        const addedImagePaths = await Promise.all(
            addedImages.map(async (file) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                const fileDataUrl = await new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
                    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
                    reader.onerror = reject;
                });

                if (existingImages.has(fileDataUrl)) {
                    return fileDataUrl;
                }

                const blob = await (await fetch(fileDataUrl)).blob();
                const request = new Request(blob as any);
                const cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);

                if (!cachedResponse) {
                    const response = await fetch(request);
                    await cache.put(request, response);
                }

                const cachedImageURL = await (cache.match(request) as any)?.url ?? fileDataUrl;

                return cachedImageURL;
            })
        );
```

get chrome-extension://hnpdlbalmgcignmohakgakgpnjncndna/[object%20Blob] nett::R_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Do you have `host_permissions` defined in your `manifest.json` ?

Comment: It doesn't work because this API doesn't support chrome-extension:// scheme. You can use IndexedDB to store the image blob directly.

Comment: Thanks that is what I did. I used IndexDB to store the image blobs.